# How to close MaterialDatePicker after selecting date

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, material-design, materialdatepicker

I want to close MaterialDatePicker after selecting a date range but it is necessary to click on "Save" button. How can I close the dialog automatically after selecting start and end date?

```
val datePicker = createDatePicker()
datePicker.show(parentFragmentManager, DATE_PICKER_DIALOG_TAG)

private fun createDatePicker(): MaterialDatePicker<Pair<Long, Long>> {
    val constraintsBuilder = createCalendarConstraints()
    val datePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
        .setTitleText(getString(R.string.select_check_in_and_check_out_date))
        .setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build())
        .build()
    datePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
        binding.selectDate.setText(datePicker.headerText.toString())
    }
    return datePicker
}

private fun createCalendarConstraints(): CalendarConstraints.Builder {
    val dateValidator: DateValidator = DateValidatorPointForward.now()
    return CalendarConstraints.Builder()
        .setValidator(dateValidator)
}
```

Comment: can you achieve this task?